# Mirror object around a circle?

Tags: modifiers, objects

Ok so I am trying to get a simple cylinder to mirror around a circle to make what would look like Gatling gun barrels. I have tried to mirror the object around a empty point and than use an array modifier but I am having some problems getting it to circle around the object. Can someone please point me in the right direction on what I am doing wrong. I know that using a mirror on an object and than using an array modifier around an empty point works I have seen it done I just cant seem to copy the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to include the mirror modifier in your setup, as the array modifier can do it all on its own. The important thing to note is that you want to use an 'Object Offset' and turn off 'Relative Offset'. You'll use the target object's rotation, which should be equal to 360/count. In this case, the empty was rotated 60 degrees, since the count is 6.

[image]

For some hands-on experimentation, have a look at the [.blend](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=44150)