# Modifier 'Array' and 'Curve'

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edit-mode

I have a '*Bezier Circle*' and I'm trying to make the object go follow the circle.
I add the array and curve modifier then select the circle (scale is set to 1.00 for both the object and the curve) but the object gets distorted. Why is that?
[image]
Additionally, I am also struggling to merge the first and last copies when I use Array and Curve modifiers; I tried to able '*Merge*' in the Array modifier and I was thinkin that the first/last copies should merge when they get close enough but it does not work.
[image]

Any thoughts?

I have found the reason why the object got 'stretched' when I applied the *Curve* modifier. The problem was that when I added the *Bezier* curve I scaled it 'normally' and the *Weight* and *Radius* did not go back to 1.00 even though I applied the scale.

[image]

The solution is to add the *Bezier* curve and then scale by radius.

The problem of merging the last and first copies I solved by using the Weld modifier.

Comment: make sure that both the origins of the object and curves are at the same position, also select your curve and in Edit mode select all and right click and set the radius to 1?

Comment: Hi :). The Array ends aren't merging because it's applied *before* the Curve modifier. To merge the vertices, add a Weld modifier at the end.

Answer (score 3):

**Array and Curve vs Array with Object Offset.**

To demonstrate the difference between two setups. Add a simple  joined 2 edge mesh.  -1, 0, 1 along $X$ axis (all y and z coords 0)

**Array & Curve**

[image]

Add default Bezier circle, and on edge mesh a default array modifier, fit the circle and a curve modifier also pointing to circle.

Notice that the mesh is deformed by the curve modifier such that each vertex sits on the circle

Despite "fit curve" a unit length edge is not a great fit to $2\pi r$ circle & have scaled to produce a regular octagon (close enough) on the unit circle.

As mentioned by @JachymMichael in comment above a weld modifier would be required to merge the last and first vert.

**Object Offset.**

[image]

In this example, take the same setup, and in edit mode selected all and shifted in $Y$ such that its object origin is at (0, 0, 0) but it sits atop the circle at radius 1.

An array modifier is added using only object offset. An  empty placed at the origin is the offsetting object.

With a count of 4 and rotating the empty by 90 degrees  (360 / count) gives us 4 undeformed copies around the circle. The merge of the array modifier will deal with start and end vertices.

[How to make a circular array using offset object as center?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6023/how-to-make-a-circular-array-using-offset-object-as-center)

[Mirror object around a circle?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66605/mirror-object-around-a-circle)