# Why are the array modifier and curve affecting my object?

Tags: edit-mode

I want to use an array modifier to place my object along a curve. I have tried to do it by using using both an array modifier and curve modifier (see picture 1) as well as only an array modifier and using the Object Offset and selecting the curve (pic 2). I get different results with both.

Origin and 3D Cursor are at World Origin.

Why are the array modifier and curve deforming my object?

[image]

[image]

The end result should be something like this:
[image]

I want to get a result like the fourth picture. Yes it is deforming the planes on the outer sides of the curve, but it is not changing or affecting the geometry of the planes. It is just 'wrapping' the planes around the curve. That is what I want.

[image]

The file: [image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/238562/modifier-array-and-curve?rq=1

Comment: Could you please draw what are you trying to achieve at the end? The Curve modifier will deform the object, and Array with Object Offset may also deform the object if it has been scaled

Comment: I added another picture for end result. So the first picture is getting pretty close, but it is still deforming the upper parts.

Comment: @JohnEason I don't really understand what they are doing

Comment: The Curve modifier will always deform, but you can just array a plane, activate its Instancing > Faces and parent your wooden batten to the plane

Comment: If you want to know _why_ the _Curve Modifier_ is deforming your object, that is very easy to explain: in the modifiers tab, you can find it under **Deform** which is a first hint, and in the Blender Documentation on this modifier, the first sentence is: _"The Curve modifier provides a simple but efficient method of deforming a mesh along a curve object."_

Comment: Maybe I should not have used the word deform. I mean I should be able to just place a plane along a curve without it affecting the geometry right? Like in the second picture it is making the planes much smaller. I want something like the fourth picture - just placing planes along the shape of the curve

Comment: Apply the rotation and scale of your curve and in Edit mode select all and right click >Set Curve Radius > 1?

Comment: Or please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: The Array modifier together with the Curve Modifier works now. But when I only use the Array Modifier with Object Offset, nothing happens now. I will upload the file

Comment: Why do you want to use Array modifier with Object Offset? If you say that it works now why don't you keep it as it is?

Comment: Mainly for learning purposes. Trying to be able to work with both ways. Because in this case I am working with a curve, but if I for example work with an Empty then you would use the Object Offset. So trying to understand it.

Comment: The Object Offset won't let you make the shape you show (chair) so I'm not sure why you want to use it, unless you're trying to do another shape, in that case, please show the shape

Comment: Ah okay, clear! I know enough for now, thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

You've probably scaled your curve, which deforms the instances of your object, to fix that apply the rotation and scale of your curve and in *Edit* mode select all and right click > *Set Curve Radius > 1* and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

As for the *Array* in *Object Offset* mode, it will modify the array according to the location, rotation and scale of the selected object, it won't allow you to create such a shape.